# Extract Record Key Types into Union Type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, extract, union

Given:

```
interface ActionA {
  type: 'AAAA';
  stuff: string[];
}

interface ActionB {
  type: 'BBBB';
  otherStuff: string[];
}
```

Is there something like:

```
type ActionTypes = ExtractToUnion<ActionA | ActionB, "type">;
```

To construct a type of:

```
type ActionTypes = 'AAAA' | 'BBBB';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [index access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to look up `type` property of a union:

```
type ActionTypes = (ActionA | ActionB)["type"]; // "AAAA" | "BBBB"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iVyDeAsAFDLJgCeADhAFzIDkqzqDA3CWQM5gCuMMejyigA5gG0Auh2IBfEiVCRYiFOkw4AQgU7lqdRpqOb2urGAAW0AMp8BQsCJATpJecRKUaaDNhAAVfS5kAF5kAAp1PzwAHx8NEE0ASnEAIi8IVOkgA)